# Create a repository in VSTS by c#

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

I found some articles regarding to make a repository on GitHub by command line and GitHub API. But I would like to create a repository in VSTS by c# and probably with VSTS API.

How can I approach this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the VSTS API and you can find it in the [documentation here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories#create-a-repository).

In short you will have to send a POST request to the URL:

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/?api-version={version}
```

With the following content:

```
{
  "name": {string},
  "project": {
    "id": {guid}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look at the REST API documentation of VSTS. There is a section about Git and in more detail Git repositories including how to create a repo via a POST request:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories#createarepository

Comment: Just as a tip for future answers - your answer is perfectly correct, but it is recommended to add some code sample to your answer as well, because if the link went down, the answer could not be used anymore :-) .